# Unable to run yum update on virtualized centOS 6.3

Tags: centos, yum

I am running a virtualized CentOS 6.3 on a Windows 7 computer. The computer (4 GB RAM) is connected to a corporate network.

When I run yum update, it shows some progress, then eventually the VM (2 GB RAM) freezes, this has happened nearly 5 times now.

I've also tried updating using the graphic package manager, same thing happens, any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried `yum clean all` first?

Answer (score 0):

The YUM installer allocates memory and mirror plugins create threads. I managed to update a VPS(128k) running Centos 6.0 to 6.6 as follows:

- edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf` and set maxthreads to 1
- stop as many processes as possible. For example: `service stop httpd`
- remove any unwanted packages. For example: `yum remove man-pages`
- Run the following script/commands:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  date
  yum clean all
  echo "Starting Update........."
  for package in `yum -q check-update | awk '{print $1}'`
  do
      echo "*** Updating $package"
      yum -y update $package
  done
  yum clean all
  yum -y update
  date
  ```